# Compass compiles from two projects

Tags: compass-sass

I've just created the 2nd of 2 Drupal sites on my local environment - both styled via sass/compass.

When I run compass watch on the new site, it compiles the scss from the first site into the new site's css file.

How can I make sure the two are separated?

There's a config.rb-file in each  (drupal) site's theme folder site:/sites/all/themes/themename/config.rb

Contents of both files are:

```
relative_assets = true
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
javascripts_dir = "js"
fonts_dir = "fonts"
output_style = :nested
environment = :development
```

I'm executing Compass Watch from the theme folder of the site I'm working on.

Comment: What's your config file ? Where is it located ?  Where do you execute the watch command ?

Comment: Hi @Kangouroops - updated original question with answers to your questions. Thanks